# Cryptic MSSQL error message

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Previous related thread: [Join in Query WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088228/join-in-query-where-clause)

I'm getting this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

My SQL Statement:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name products.extended_description, products.catalogid, products.image1, products.image2, products.stock, products.price, manufacturer.manufacturer, products.weight 
FROM products 
JOIN manufacturer ON (products.manufacturer = manufacturer.id) 
JOIN product_category ON (product_category.catalogid = products.catalogid) 
JOIN category ON (category.id = product_category.id) 
WHERE category.category_name = ?;
```

What do I have wrong here? My statement looks correct to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma after `products.name`

Should be:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.extended_description, ...
```

Comment: oh boy... i've been staring at this screen for too long today. thank you. will mark as correct when timer runs out.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma between `products.name` and `products.extended_description`.  It thinks that products.extended_description is the alias.  If it is then put []s around it.  `[products.extended_description]`.  Otherwise put in the missing comma.

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.extended_description, products.catalogid,
    products.image1, products.image2, products.stock, products.price, 
    manufacturer.manufacturer, products.weight 
FROM products 
JOIN manufacturer ON (products.manufacturer = manufacturer.id) 
JOIN product_category ON (product_category.catalogid = product.catalogid) 
JOIN category ON (category.id = product_category.id) 
WHERE category.category_name = ?;
```